# Guessing game by using while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

x=random.randint(1,9)


print(x)

guess=2

print('You have {} chance to guess the number'.format(guess+1))

y=int(input('Your guess: '))

while x!=y:
    print('Guess left: {}'.format(guess))
    y=int(input('Your guess: '))
    guess-=1
    
    if guess==0:
        print('Try again. The number was {}'.format(x))
        break
    
print('Well done')
```

Hello, when I make x is not equal to y deliberately 3 times or make x is not equal to y deliberately 2 times and make x is equal to y thirdly, I get 'Try again..' and 'Well done' messages at the same time. How can I fix it? Please do not use while true or special functions, thanks.

Comment: What do you want it to do? When the while loop ends, `'Well Done'` will always print.

Comment: I do not want program to print well done if all guesses are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

---

```
import random

x=random.randint(1,9)
print(x)

guess=3

print(f'You have {guess} chance to guess the number')

flag = 1
while (guess and flag):
    y=int(input('Your guess: '))

    guess-=1
    print(f'Guess left: {guess}')
    
    if guess==0 and (x!=y): 
        print(f'Try again. The number was {x}')
        
    if (x==y):
        print('Well done')
        flag = 0
```

---

```
6
You have 3 chance to guess the number
Your guess: 1
Guess left: 2
Your guess: 2
Guess left: 1
Your guess: 3
Guess left: 0
Try again. The number was 6
```

---

```
6
You have 3 chance to guess the number
Your guess: 6
Guess left: 2
Well done
```

---

```
3
You have 3 chance to guess the number
Your guess: 1
Guess left: 2
Your guess: 2
Guess left: 1
Your guess: 3
Guess left: 0
Well done
```

**Edit**:

```
import random

x=random.randint(1,9)


print(x)

guess=2

print('You have {} chance to guess the number'.format(guess+1))

y=int(input('Your guess: '))


while x!=y:
    print('Guess left: {}'.format(guess))
    y=int(input('Your guess: '))
    guess-=1
    
    if guess==0 and (x!=y): # <--here
        print('Try again. The number was {}'.format(x))
        break
if (x==y):   # <-- here
    print('Well done')
```

Comment: When you make x!=y first two steps and x=y at third, you still get two messages at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, but Is there any more basic solution because I guess we are using while true here.

Comment: @blitz: check the edited version. I just have added few conditions in your code.

Comment: Yeah thanks this is better and working but we have already written x!=y next to while loop, why should we repeat it again next to if condition in while loop?

Comment: actually suppose this is going to be your last chance to guess and you guess it correctly but that will give you `Try again. The number was 5  
Well done` you come out of loop only when the number you have given matches with the `x`. Since you are comparing the previous entered value with the x in the while loop. But inside it you provide the current entered value.

Comment: If you will see before while loop you have entered the `y` value which you are comparing but inside the while loop you are giving the value of `y` . when it will arrive at guess==0 condition it won't have any idea whether the number matched or not since your compared the previous entered `y` value to the `x`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what your problem was. All you need to do is put the print('Well Done!') into an if statement or use an else.

```
import random

x = random.randint(1, 9)

print(x)

guess = 2

print('You have {} chance to guess the number'.format(guess + 1))

y = int(input('Your guess: '))

while x != y:
    print('Guess left: {}'.format(guess))
    y = int(input('Your guess: '))
    guess -= 1

    if guess == 0:
        print('Try again. The number was {}'.format(x))
        break
if x==y:
    print('Well done')
```

Comment: When you make x!=y first two steps and x=y at third, you still get two messages at the same time.